# Vectorized cumulative concatenation with Numpy arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array that looks like

```
array([array([1]), array([2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

and I want to obtain an array that looks like

```
array([array([1]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

Basically, I'm looking for a function that is similar to `np.cumsum` that works on numpy arrays.
How do I do this? Also, is it more time efficient to have the internal elements as numpy arrays rather than lists, or does it make no difference because the data type is `object` either way? Could I make it faster by somehow restricting the data type like

```
np.array([np.array([1]), np.array([2, 3]), np.array([4, 5, 6])], dtype=np.ndarray)
```

Comment: Typically how many arrays would you have? Like it is `3` in this sample case. And, typically what are the lengths of those arrays?

Comment: Would suggest looping owing to the variable size problem. Should be an easy implementation too.

Comment: Do you need all arrays to have separate data or can the shorter ones be views into the longer ones? - If the second, it is most efficient to concatenate everything and then slice into that.

Comment: I'm expecting variable size arrays (not necessarily incremental like in the example), with around ~100,000 total arrays and each array having on average 40 elements.

Comment: `dtype=np.ndarray` doesn't do anything different.  If the `dtype` is anything other than the standard numeric and string dtypes, it makes `object`.  Print the array to see for yourself.  I suspect the best alternative to PaulPanzer's array split is to work with a list of lists.  List iteration and `extend` are faster than the array equivalents.

Comment: @hpaulj but with a list of lists you have the same memory problem as with non data sharing arrays. And you can't use `extend` because you need to keep the unextended version, also.

Answer (score 3):

The following approach concatenates everything first and then slices into that. This means that the data buffer is shared by all partial arrays. To give every one their own memory would require (depending on dtype) a TB of RAM.

```
from timeit import timeit
import numpy as np

def cumconc(A):
    total = np.concatenate(A)
    return np.array([*map(total.__getitem__, map(slice, np.fromiter(map(len,A),int,len(A)).cumsum()))])
```

Equivalent list comprehension:

```
    return np.array([total[:j] for j in np.cumsum([len(j) for j in A])])
```

Example:

```
chunks = np.array([np.full(np.random.randint(20,61), i) for i in range(100000)])
```

`chunks` looks like

```
array([array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0]),
       array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
       array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]),
       ...,
       array([99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997,
       99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997,
       99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997,
       99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997,
       99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997, 99997]),
       array([99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998,
       99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998,
       99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998,
       99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998,
       99998, 99998, 99998, 99998, 99998]),
       array([99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999,
       99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999,
       99999, 99999, 99999])], dtype=object)
```

Apply function:

```
cumconc(chunks)
```

Result:

```
array([array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0]),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
       array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2]),
       ..., array([    0,     0,     0, ..., 99997, 99997, 99997]),
       array([    0,     0,     0, ..., 99998, 99998, 99998]),
       array([    0,     0,     0, ..., 99999, 99999, 99999])],
      dtype=object)
```

How fast?

```
timeit(lambda: cumconc(chunks), number=10)
# 0.8433913141489029
```

Comment: How does cumconc work? If possible, could you write the code as multiple lines so that I can understand what happens one step at a time?

Comment: I've rewritten it as a list comprehension. Should be easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `itertools.accumulate` and `np.concatenate` with custom function to achieve it. However, I don't how efficient it is

```
from itertools import accumulate
n = array([array([1]), array([2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)
np.array(list(accumulate(n, lambda x, y: np.concatenate([x, y]))))

Out[1785]:
array([array([1]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])],
      dtype=object)
```